# Convert list<base> class to list<derived> class in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have a base class(Directory) that has following parameters :

```
string Name;
string Path;
List<Directory> SubDirectory;
```

Now i want to make a new class that will be extension of this class with a new property :

```
Bool Valid ;
```

so i write the following code for the derived class (DirectoryExt):

```
Public class DirectoryExt : Directory

{
    Public bool Valid {get; set;}

    public DirectoryExt( Directory directory)

    {
       this.Name = directory.Name;
       this.Path = directory.Path;
       this.SubDirectory = directory.Subdirectory;
       this.Valid = false;
    } 

}
```

The problem here is how to convert this `List<Directory> SubDirectory` into `List<DirectoryExt> SubDirectory` when i create a `DirectoryExt(derived)` object from an existing `Directory(bas`e) object ??

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: is anything bad on iteration over List<Directory> and add new items to List<DirectoryExt>?

Comment: What's exception you got?

Comment: when i try to get SubDirectory from DirectoryExt , it raises an object conversion exception..

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ to Objects:

```
this.SubDirectory = directory.SubDirectory.Select(s => new DirectoryExt(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file.

Comment: this is not working... here SubDirectory is a list of Directory and when i write like this it says cannot convert List<Directory> into list<DirectoryExt)

Answer (score 0):

this.SubDirectory = new ObservableCollection< Directory >();

```
        if (directory.SubDirectory != null || directory.SubDirectory.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in directory.SubDirectory.Select(s => new DirectoryExt(s)).ToList())
            {
                this.SubDirectory.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

This is correct solution to it... i have tested it and it worked.